Natural transformation using tikz
I can draw this:
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, node distance=2cm, auto]

\node (w) at (0,0) {$w$};
\node (x) at (2,2) {$x$};
\node (y) at (4,0) {$y$};
\node (z) at (6,2) {$z$};

\draw[->] (x) -- node[left] {$e$} (w);
\draw[->] (x) -- node[below left] {$f$} (y);
\draw[->] (z) -- node[above right] {$g$} (y);



% Nodes for F functor
\node (Fw) at (8,2) {$F(w)$};
\node (Fx) at (10,4) {$F(x)$};
\node (Fy) at (12,2) {$F(y)$};
\node (Fz) at (14,4) {$F(z)$};

\draw[->] (Fx) -- node[above left] {$F(e)$} (Fw);
\draw[->] (Fx) -- node[below left] {$F(f)$} (Fy);
\draw[->] (Fz) -- node[above right] {$F(g)$} (Fy);


\node (Gw) at (8,-2) {$G(w)$};
\node (Gx) at (10,0) {$G(x)$};
\node (Gy) at (12,-2) {$G(y)$};
\node (Gz) at (14,0) {$G(z)$};

% Arrows for G functor
\draw[->] (Gx) -- node[above left] {$G(e)$} (Gw);
\draw[->] (Gx) -- node[below left] {$G(f)$} (Gy);
\draw[->] (Gz) -- node[above right] {$G(g)$} (Gy);


\draw[->] (Fw) -- node[left] {$\alpha_w$} (Gw);
\draw[->] (Fx) -- node[right] {$\alpha_x$} (Gx);
\draw[->] (Fy) -- node[left] {$\alpha_y$} (Gy);
\draw[->] (Fz) -- node[right] {$\alpha_z$} (Gz);

\end{tikzpicture}

I am unable to connect both pictures.


Working with the code replacement from CarLaTex (Edit) here are the missing parts.

OPs, please ...
... always provide code, which compiles.
Shifting the left diagram
Instead of changing all x-coordinates manually, I used the \shortcut{}, which accepts the shift-value and draws the left part. Adjust the shift as needed.
    \shortcut{-4}

As I indicated for label "g" sometimes labels are too close. Using anchors (and dotted shapes to show it) is highly recommended. // I left the parts with this problem in the right diagram as-are.
The missing arrows
    % ~~~ the missing arrows (usually drawn later ~~~
%   \draw[<-] (6, 2) -- node[anchor=south]{$F$} (4, 2); 
    \draw[<-] (6, 2) to [bend right] node[anchor=south]{$F$} (4, 2);    
    \draw[<-] (6,-1) .. controls +(-110:.7) and +(.3,-.3) .. 
                        node[anchor=north]{$G$} (4,-1);
    
    \draw[->,double distance=2pt] (5,1) -- 
                            node[anchor=west,pos=.4]{$\alpha$} (5,0);

Now that there is more space between the two diagrams the 3 arrows can be drawn. It's always a good idea to start with the simples form, a straight line, and introduce refinement later. Please note, that here I draw the lines from right to left, hence the <- syntax.

the commented out line shows the simple start
next line replaces -- by to [bend right]
if you need more fancy arrows, use controls, where the first uses polar notation to specify the control-points, in relative coordinates indicated by +
the vertical double arrow explains itself
besides using an anchor, I also shifted the label closer to its beginning via pos=.4, which perhaps looks nicer

Also here the coordinates may not be optimal, but are easy to adjust.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand\shortcut[1]{%   to shift everything
    \node (w) at (#1+0,0) {$w$};
    \node (x) at (#1+2,2) {$x$};
    \node (y) at (#1+4,0) {$y$};
    \node (z) at (#1+6,2) {$z$};

    \draw[->] (x) -- node[left] {$e$} (w);
    \draw[->] (x) -- node[below left] {$f$} (y);
%   \draw[->] (z) -- node[above right] {$g$} (y);}  % g is hard to see
    \draw[->] (z) -- node[anchor=north west,draw,dotted] {$g$} (y);}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth}, node distance=2cm, auto]

    \shortcut{-4}
    
    % ~~~ the missing arrows (usually drawn later ~~~
%   \draw[<-] (6, 2) -- node[anchor=south]{$F$} (4, 2); 
    \draw[<-] (6, 2) to [bend right] node[anchor=south]{$F$} (4, 2);    
    \draw[<-] (6,-1) .. controls +(-110:.7) and +(.3,-.3) .. 
                        node[anchor=north]{$G$} (4,-1);
    
    \draw[->,double distance=2pt] (5,1) -- 
                            node[anchor=west,pos=.4]{$\alpha$} (5,0);
    
    
    % Nodes for F functor
    \node (Fw) at (8,2) {$F(w)$};
    \node (Fx) at (10,4) {$F(x)$};
    \node (Fy) at (12,2) {$F(y)$};
    \node (Fz) at (14,4) {$F(z)$};
    
    \draw[->] (Fx) -- node[above left] {$F(e)$} (Fw);
    \draw[->] (Fx) -- node[below left] {$F(f)$} (Fy);
    \draw[->] (Fz) -- node[above right] {$F(g)$} (Fy);
    
    
    \node (Gw) at (8,-2) {$G(w)$};
    \node (Gx) at (10,0) {$G(x)$};
    \node (Gy) at (12,-2) {$G(y)$};
    \node (Gz) at (14,0) {$G(z)$};
    
    % Arrows for G functor
    \draw[->] (Gx) -- node[above left] {$G(e)$} (Gw);
    \draw[->] (Gx) -- node[below left] {$G(f)$} (Gy);
    \draw[->] (Gz) -- node[above right] {$G(g)$} (Gy);
    
    
    \draw[->] (Fw) -- node[left] {$\alpha_w$} (Gw);
    \draw[->] (Fx) -- node[right] {$\alpha_x$} (Gx);
    \draw[->] (Fy) -- node[left] {$\alpha_y$} (Gy);
    \draw[->] (Fz) -- node[right] {$\alpha_z$} (Gz);

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

